# Best way to auto-restart mono process after crash

Tags: debian, crash, process, automation

I'm on a shared sever without sudo.  I'm using a program running off mono that crashes frequently on a Debian server.  What's the best way to have the process auto-restart?

Comment: You might want to re-word the question as "**How can I** have the process auto-restart?" instead of "What's the best way", because "best way" is opinion-based and could cause the question to be closed.

Comment: Also, it depends on how you're starting this process. Is it via `/etc/init.d`? Are you using a version of Debian that runs systemd (e.g. does `systemctl` exist as a valid command?) Or are you just running it from the CLI like `mono foo.exe`?

Comment: I'm running the program from CLI.  It is running systemd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In systemd you can create a `service` file to (re)start your process. You can add this file in `/etc/systemd/system` or in `/etc/systemd/user`.

This will take care of starting your program when the server reboots or when your program crashes. You can look at the existing files there for examples and also have a look at the [manual](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html).

If you just want to start it from the commandline and have it restart when it exits, you can create a bash script that wraps your command. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

while (true) do
   echo starting...
   # your command goes here instead of sleep
   sleep 4
   # show result
   exitcode=$?
   echo "exit code of command is $exitcode"
done
```

This is the simplest form, which does no checking at all.

Comment: your shell script worked wonderfully, thank you.